# mouse-pointer strange behaviour

Tags: lubuntu, mouse-pointer

I´ve got a question concerning my mouse-pointer.

From time to time my mouse-pointer changes to a symbol that represents something like an arrow melted together with a loading-circle.
I tried to find out something about it and believe that it means *"background activity"*.

So far so good. But there´s one thing I cannot really explain:

Whenever I open my file-manager **pcmanfm** in a "normal" way, i.e. by clicking on a desktop-icon or the respective symbol in the task-bar, the window
immediately opens - without any mouse-pointer activity.

However when I start **pcmanfm** by clicking the key-combination *"WIN-key + e"* the window opens as well but with the addition of the "background-activity" symbol.
That one can be seen for about 20 seconds and then vanishes.

Another example:

I use *firejail* (sandbox) and the associated tool *firetools*. When opening *firetools* from the menu there´s the same thing: background activity-symbol for a few seconds. But when opening via command line: no symbol whatsowever.

Just to be clear: everything works fine without any delay - even with that mouse-pointer-symbol. I just want to know why that is?

*system: Linux/Lubuntu 16.04.4 LTS, 64 bit*

Answer (score 0):

In the meantime I could solve the mystery. With the help of ondoho from linuxquestions.org. If anyone is interested here´s some background info:

> File: ~/.config/openbox/lxde-rc.xml
>
> please have a look at that file. (warning! XML is hard to read without
>   syntax highlighting!) the name might differ slightly, but you'll find
>   it (*). you will notice that most app launch entries have a section
>   that says something like this:
>
> ```
> <startupnotify>
>         <enabled>yes</enabled>
>       </startupnotify>
> ```
>
> startup notification is a mechanism that displays the background activity pointer until it is able to recognize
>   that the application started. unfortunately, sometimes it is not able
>   to recognize that, so the background activity pointer just stays there
>   until it times out.
>
> that's what you're seeing; it does not mean that there actually is any
>   background activity, or that the launched application has a problem.
>   it simply means that the mechanism that displays the background
>   activity pointer is broken. and your system remains perfectly usable.
>
> a small annoyance, but harmless.

Source: https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/mouse-pointer-symbol-background-activity-4175626657/